# Why my agent collision doesn't work (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, collision

I have an agent called cube (cube its just the name, it is a square in reality). Every cube falls and stops on the ground, and I want them to detect the other cubes and stack up.

I am having problems with this method for detecting collision: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY-c2HO2liA&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA

I made 2 for loops and all but it doesn't work for some reason.

this is the main script:

```
var cubes = [];
var nb = 10;       //number of cubes
var gravity = .1;
var sz = 10;       //cube size

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    cubes.push(new Cube());
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    cubes[i].show();
    for (var j = 0; j < cubes.length; j++) {

      if (i != j && !cubes[i].collide(cubes[j]) && !(cubes[i].pos.y + sz > height)) {
        cubes[i].pos.y += gravity; 

      }
    }

  }
}
```

this is the cube function linked with p5.js in an HTML file:

```
function Cube() {

  this.rx = (round((random(0, width - sz)) / sz) * sz);
  this.ry = (round((random(sz, height - sz)) / sz) * sz);

  this.pos = createVector(this.rx, this.ry);


  this.show = function() {
    fill(220);
    noStroke();
    rect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, sz, sz);
  }

  this.collide = function(other) {

    if (this.pos.y + sz == other.pos.y && this.pos.x == other.pos.x) {
      return true;      
    } else {
      return false;

    }

  }

}
```

I want the cubes to stack up when they hit the ground but they only pass through each other completely ignoring the collision I've set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is coming from the fact that you are using ==, please try modifying this line :

```
 if (this.pos.y + sz == other.pos.y && this.pos.x == other.pos.x) {
```

into

```
  if (this.pos.y + sz > other.pos.y  &&  this.pos.y  <= other.pos.y+sz  &&
  this.pos.x < other.pos.x+sz && this.pos.x + sz > other.pos.x)
```

Comment: I tried it and doesn't seem to work either, the cubes are spawned on a rounded coordinate based on their size, so 10px squares will spawn every 10px (ex: 290,150) not (292,153) so they don't need the > or <

Comment: there is a case that i didn't see, lemme amend the answer with that case (cube falling at left) , I'm speculating that the cubes are going down (so their Y is increasing)

Comment: still doesn't work, I don't understand why. Did it work for you?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle it please  ?

Comment: Here it is working, you had an issue as well with the collision detection system (any collision should stop letting them fall), and cubes creations. Honestly, the end result looks very cool :)